# Perfectly blending dots along infinity symbol path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending-objects

I am trying to figure out how to produce the below image in Illustrator.

Is there a systematic way to do it via first blending the dots and then via “Replace Spine”? (Or, perhaps, there is an better method to do it.)

[image]

Comment: I'd use a pattern or scatter brush for this, but I'm not too sure about what procedure to follow. Googling those terms might help you a lot, though.

Comment: I think this is something which has to be done manually to be done correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can make this using blending mode with the scattered brush the size of the circle may vary since only random and fixed is the option for brush.

First draw the circle a big and a tiny circle.

Blend it using object-> blend and give the specified steps as 5.

[image]

now blend it. object make blend or alt+ctrl+B

[image]

Now select the objects right click transform --> reflect

[image]

select the objects right click transform --> reflect choose **horizontal** and **copy**

[image]

Again select the objects right click transform --> reflect choose **vertictal**

[image]

You can add a circle in the middle which is little larger in size.

Do the same method for the objects on the top left. (the specicific distance should be 3)

[image]

[image]

You need to adjust the spline using the direct selection tool (A)

[image]

Group them (ctrl +G)
[image]

Now select the objects right click transform --> reflect choose **horizontal** and **copy**

Here you go

[image]

Thanks

Digiscape Gallery

Comment: How do you achieve the consistent distance between the individual dots with the blend tool? When I try to do that, the distance varies strongly and the bigger dots overlap, like this: http://i.imgur.com/SQJfFUT.png

Comment: Digiscape Gallery; thanks for sparing your time. I understand that the only way is doing it manually.

Comment: @blackened if this has answered your question please accept it as the answer, if it hasn't please make an edit to your question with what you've tried.